# My Datareader doesn't want to Dataread

Tags: .net, vb.net, datareader

Here is my code :

```
   Public Function AccidentReport(machineID As Integer) As Integer
    Dim Colours As Integer
    connection.Open()

    command = New SqlCommand("Select [Date],[Investigation Date] From MaintenanceRecord Where [Record Type] ='Accident Report' AND ID=@ID", connection)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", machineID)
    datareader = command.ExecuteReader()

    While datareader.Read()
        If datareader.Item("Date") = "" Then
            Colours = 1
            '^Red
        ElseIf datareader.Item("Date") <> "" And datareader.Item("Investigation Date") <> "" Then
            Colours = 3
            '^Green
        End If
    End While
    datareader.Close()
    connection.Close()
    Return Colours
End Function
```

At the moment there is no records in the table in which i am selecting so I guess that's the problem so my question is `Can i force my Datareader to set Colours=1 if it doesn't read any data or is there a way I could force this before the Datareader in VB.NET?`

Comment: Why not simple `Dim Colours As Integer = 1`? If data is read then value will be updated else its value will be 1.

Comment: @Satpal Your assumption will not be correct for datareader.Item("Date") <> "" And datareader.Item("Investigation Date") = "".  It will/must be blank in that case.

Comment: That's a failing of the OP's code to handle anything outside two very narrow conditions. The addition of an `Else` block would take care of that and make the default of 1 valid.

Comment: @Kallumasaurus Is there an "Else" option here, that is other than 1 or 3?

Comment: I've fixed my problem , Just set the Tab Index in the ASP.NET page to Show the image i required as default. Cheers for the concern though.

Answer (score 0):

set the value before you execute read

```
...
Colours = 1 ' Add this line
While datareader.Read()
    If datareader.Item("Date") = "" Then
        Colours = 1
        '^Red
    ElseIf datareader.Item("Date") <> "" And datareader.Item("Investigation Date") <> "" Then
        Colours = 3
        '^Green
    End If
End While
...
```

Or as @Satpal  stated, just initialize variable with default value

```
Dim Colours As Integer = 1
```

Comment: Your scenario does not cater for datareader.Item("Date") <> "" And datareader.Item("Investigation Date") = "". It will/must be blank in that case (according to the code)